Laravel-Livewire-3 event listening not working
Hi i am using event listening for add to cart functionality, my aim is to create general addToCart() method and then can call by whole application.
product-box.blade.php
<div wire:click="addingToCart('{{ $data['slug'] }}')" class="hover:text-primary cursor-pointer">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping text-primary"></i>
            Add to Cart
   </div>

ProductBox.php
 public function addingToCart($pr_slug){
        $this->dispatch('add-to-cart', slug: $pr_slug);
    }

Cart.php
use Livewire\Attributes\On; 

    #[On('add-to-cart')]
        public function addToCart($slug){
            //do my add to cart logic
           
        }

looking forward for help

Are both components present on the same page at the same time?

Oh, my components are not on the same page, thanks you saved my 8 hours.
